# django-piston: request.data availability within DELETE handlers

Tags: django, http, rest, django-piston

django-piston appears to create a data attribute on the request object before it gets to the Handler phase. This data is available, for example, in the PUT and POST handlers by accessing request.data.

However, in the DELETE handler, the data is not available.

I would like to modify django-piston to make this data available but I have no real idea on where to start. Any ideas? Where does the data attribute originate from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this for myself. The short hacky answer is that the method

```
translate_mime(request)
```

from piston.utils needs to be run on the request to make the data attribute available.

The overall fix for this would be to make a change in the Piston source code itself in resource.py to execute the translate_mime method for DELETE actions. Currently it only does to automatically for PUT and POST.

But, like I said, you can actually just manually call translate_mime in the actual handler method and it works fine.